# How do I write a log file from my SQL Azure App Service Web App?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Web API deployed on Azure **App Service** as a **Web App**.

I've turned on **Diagnostic Logging** for the **App Service**.

[image]

From within the API code, when I try to write a log message to a file, apparently, the file system relative path `"."` resolves to `"D:\Windows\system32\"` on the target machine/VM/container.

I know this because I have my test action method set up to print the entire exception as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/test/log")]
public async Task<string> LogAsync()
{
  try
  {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(".\\log.txt", "Test log entry.");

    return await Task.FromResult("Passed");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    return ex.ToString();
  }
}
```

And it returns the following result:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'D:\Windows\system32\log.txt' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path,
>   Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean
>   checkHost)    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean
>   append, Encoding encoding)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalAppendAllText(String path, String contents,
>   Encoding encoding)    at System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path,
>   String contents)    at
>   My.Web.API.Controllers.TestController.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   C:\My.Web.API\My.Web.API\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 125

Comment: You might need to look at app insights https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Currently You are trying to save logs under D:\Windows\System32 folder which shouldn't be allowed as you are getting access denied error.
Please try to change the path to D:\Home\Logfiles\Application which is the source directory for application logging.

Also just to update , For Application logging, you can turn on the file system option temporarily for debugging purposes. This option turns off automatically in 12 hours. You can also turn on the blob storage option to select a blob container to write logs to.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs for more information on the default locations for logs.

Let me know if you need any other information on this.

This is hierarchy of your azure app when you will see it form KUDU

[image]

Comment: You have really not answered my question. I am not *trying to write to `D:\Windows\System32`*. I am simply trying to write to a log file in the `bin` folder from where my application is running. At some point, I would like to write to a more meaningful location, but for now, my intention is to find out how to write log files to a specific folder?

Comment: By using this ".\\log.txt" you are actually writing your log in D:\Windows\system32. for application logging you need to change the path.

Comment: And that's *precisely what I already report in my question is happening* and precisely what I am asking -- why does it resolve to `system32` and how to write to a more meaningful path, which you haven't answered.

Comment: With your last update to your answer, you are making a little bit of sense now. You seem to be suggesting that I go to the root physical path where my application is deployed, and that is denoted by `/` and then to the `Logs` folder within that. But still, if you or someone could write a clearer answer, that would help.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was trying to say. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Should I edit your answer to answer the question directly?

Comment: Sure . Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you. I'll do it in a few minutes.

Comment: Copied without attribution from https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/0df460dc02fec1e61e8821c5b5e48207a8abfd47/articles/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs.md